# How to Debug on Chrome 31 for android

Tags: android, debugging, google-chrome, remote-debugging

When I used chrome 30, or earlier version at android, I was able to set up the debug options by menu --> setting --> advanced ... 
But in chrome 31 for android, the options are invisible, and I don't know how to enable it and then remote debug it on windows.

[Remote Debugging Chrome on Android](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging)